# AWS Glue "array" Data Type - empty array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm using AWS Glue and my field is DataType is **array** in the DataCatalog.
When I'm building my Glue job, the mapping between the DataCatalog and the Job DynamicDataFrame for that array is empty.

For example, I just want to read it and drop it as JSON in other S3 bucket and the output is an empty array []

Do you know anything about it?

[The DataCatalog mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Q9F.png)

[The Job mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZHFY.png)